# LWC With iframe Height

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am trying to have an iframe inside a LWC fill the entire height of what's available, but can't seem to get it to work. According to the documentation, I think I should be able to apply `class="slds-grid_vertical-stretch"`, but it has no effect. I'm currently using css to give it a height of `85vh` which is close, but not perfect. Here's my template:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-layout class="slds-grid_vertical-stretch">
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" class="iframe">
                <iframe width=100% height=100% scrolling="true" style="border: 1px solid" src="https://someurl" > </iframe>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Hey,
Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: Pretty sure I wasn't able to get it to work.